# ImportError: cannot import name 'adam' from 'keras.optimizers'

Tags: keras

I am trying to import Keras but I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'adam' from 'keras.optimizers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/__init__.py)
```

The import is invoked here:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, MaxPool2D,Flatten, Dense, Permute, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import adam
import numpy as np
import pickle
import keras
import cv2
import sys
import dlib
import os.path
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.applications.resnet50 import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import pickle
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from keras.layers import Dropout
```

I am sure Keras is installed along with Tensorflow:

```
python3 -c 'import keras; print(keras.__version__)' // 2.4.3
```

Comment: Its Adam, capitalized, not adam

Answer (score 135, accepted):

There are two types of modules -

1. keras
2. tensorflow.keras

Here we need to use tensorflow.keras

You need to import Adam (With Capital A) from tensorflow - Keras ( Not only Keras).

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam # - Works
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import adam # - Does not work
from keras.optimizers import Adam            # - Does not work
from keras.optimizers import adam            # - Does not work
```

Answer (score 31):

recently, in the latest update of Keras API 2.5.0 , importing Adam optimizer shows the following error:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
ImportError: cannot import name 'Adam' from 'keras.optimizers'
```

instead use the following for importing optimizers (i.e. Adam) :

```
from keras.optimizers import adam_v2
optimizer = adam_v2.Adam(learning_rate=lr, decay=lr/epochs)
Model.compile(loss='--',  optimizer=optimizer  , metrics=['--'])
```

for more details, please have a look at :
https://programmerah.com/keras-nightly-import-package-error-cannot-import-name-adam-from-keras-optimizers-29815/

hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Glad of this answer has helped many people here.

Answer (score 24):

`from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam`

Try this in the 4th line(or just replace it with the above line). It worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

You can do two things:

1. Go with tensorflow

   `from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam`

This might cause you to change other `keras.*` modules to `tensorflow.kerar.*` modules.

2. Stay at keras

   `from keras.optimizers_v1 import Adam`

Adam has been shifted to optimizer_v1 module.

Comment: When I use optimizer from `from keras.optimizers_v1` it explicitly tells me to use `tf.keras.optimzers`. Full error trace is as follows `ValueError: `tf.compat.v1.keras` Optimizer (<keras.optimizer_v1.Adam object at 0x0000022A4D403048>) is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use a `tf.keras` Optimizer instead, or disable eager execution.`

Answer (score 9):

The error came from an older version of keras, in the newer version, you don't have to import Adam, it can be specified using the quote, i.e.:

```
model.compile(optimizer= "adam", loss='mse', metrics=[psnr, "accuracy"])
```

Comment: If you would like to have more variety, such as: `model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=0.9), loss='mse', metrics=[get_rmse])`

Comment: Throws error `ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam object at 0x000001F91A8BA820>`

Answer (score 7):

In the fourth line, just make `from keras.optimizers import Adam`.  It should work perfectly fine!

Comment: It doesn't work. 

`cannot import name 'Adam' from 'keras.optimizers'`

Answer (score 6):

```
from keras.optimizer_v2 import adam
```

Then call Adam from adam

```
adam.Adam(...);
```

Comment: thank you so much, I spent a day to solve this damn problem!!!

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me:

```
# importing
from keras.optimizers import adam_v2
# to use it
adam_v2.Adam(...)
```

I am on a virtual environment running `tensorflow-2.6.0` (**CPU** version, `pip` installed) with `Python3.8.7`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem after a whole day lost on this. I found that just:

`from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import adam_v2`

`adam_v2.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, clipnorm=1.0, clipvalue=0.5)`

works for me (i had v2.11.0 of tensorflow).

I also find these other optimizers in tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers:

'adadelta_v2', 'adagrad_v2', 'adam_v2', 'adamax_v2','nadam_v2','rmsprop_v2',

that you can use as

`from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import rmsprop_v2`

`rmsprop_v2.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001)`

Answer (score 1):

I am using
Name: keras
Version: 2.8.0

```
from keras.optimizers import adam_v2
```

Then to use the adam optimizer (use tf.keras.optimizers.Adam):

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line for import Adam

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```