# Imported necessary packages, but I'm still getting ImportError: cannot import name 'Adam' from 'keras.optimizers'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hpc

I have been trying to run a machine learning training program on an HPC cluster using MobaXterm for a while now and have been getting

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Adam' from 'keras.optimizers'
```

and similar errors when I run the main file which should train a model and then output a file of trained weights. I am making sure to import the necessary package relevant to the error through the line: "from keras.optimizers import Adam", so it's a mystery as to why this won't go away.

Someone in another thread suggested tensorflow.keras.optimizers instead of keras.optimizers, but that just gives me the alternative error:

```
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam object at 0x2aab0e2dd828>
```

Interestingly, the program, which is almost unedited from a github download, runs perfectly when running it on my computer locally, and also works great on Google Colab. As soon as I began sending it to the cluster the issues appear. Wonder if anyone has experience with this kind of thing and knows what I should be paying attention to. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I realized it may be helpful to show all the imports i'm doing at the beginning of the file, they are here:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np 
import os
import skimage.io as io
import skimage.transform as trans
import numpy as np
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import *  #I have tried commenting out this line but still face the same error
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from keras import backend as keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import glob

from keras.optimizers import Adam
```

Comment: How did you install keras in this cluster?

Comment: I did it through "pip install keras --user"

Comment: Which version of keras did that install? Its probably different from what you use in other computers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'adam' from 'keras.optimizers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707558/importerror-cannot-import-name-adam-from-keras-optimizers)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I simply replaced this:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
```

With this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

To deal with this error in newer version of tensorflow, we can skip importing Adam. We do not have to implicitly import the optimizer. We can just mention:

```
model.compile(optimizer= "adam", loss='mse')
```

Answer (score 1):

I was initially suggested to check my package versions. My Keras version was for some reason causing issues, so I did a pip uninstall keras and changed all my imports from, for example:

```
from keras.callbacks import
```

to like

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import
```

And this change fixed the problem