# keras vs. tensorflow.keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

Inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418955/17840900).

Why is there a difference between the 2 modules?

When would I use one over the other?

Anything else I should know?

Comment: Better to use `tensorflow.keras`. A few years ago Keras has been integrated into the TensorFlow, and in order to keep the compatibility, Keras still exist.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. Thank you :). Feel free to make that an answer and I will Accept it when it lets me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keras is a standalone high-level API that supports TensorFlow, Theano and CNTK backends. Now, Theano and CNTK are out of development.

`tf.keras` is the Keras API integrated into TensorFlow 2.

So, if you aim to use TensorFlow as your deep learning framework I recommend using `tensorflow.keras` for less headache.

Also based on a [tweet](https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/1174018651449544704?s=19) from François Chollet, the creator of Keras:

> We recommend you switch your Keras code to `tf.keras`.
>
> Both Theano and CNTK are out of development. Meanwhile, as Keras
> backends, they represent less than 4% of Keras usage. The other 96% of
> users (of which more than half are already on `tf.keras`) are better
> served with `tf.keras`.
>
> Keras development will focus on `tf.keras` going forward.
>
> Importantly, we will seek to start developing `tf.keras` in its own
> standalone GitHub repository at [keras-team/keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras) in order to make it
> much easier for 3rd party folks to contribute.